# Travelling to Peru, Ecuador, Galapagos with kids

Tags: safety, children, ecuador, peru, galapagos-islands

My wife and I are planning to go to Peru and Ecuador.  And also would like to visit Galapagos while we are there so I have quite a few questions but will start with 2:

1. Is it worth it to bring a 6 year old on such a trip?
2. Is it better to start with Galapagos first then Ecuador and finish in Peru or do it in the opposite direction?

Endpoint in either case is the US.

Comment: Hey Karlson, I'd recommend changing the name of the question to something specific.  At the moment, it is really ambiguous for anyone browsing the list of questions.

Comment: Do you plan to fly between places? Some of the required bus or car journeys are very long, maybe too long for a six year old.

Comment: It's far more likely that would be the case.  From my research 20-30 hour drives for some places.  And as used my son is to car travel that is a bit too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It depends!**

I am sure you can travel in a way that is super interesting and not too stressful for you son. This would mean flying the long distances between southern Peru and Ecuador, staying in nice hotels and don't travel too far overland every day in a rental car. But of course, all that has it's price.

If you want to use public transport and stay in cheap hotels it becomes a bit more stressful. I never traveled at night, but there are still some long bus rides during the days.

I am sure the animals on Galapagos would be very interesting for a six year old. Inca ruins maybe less so.

I think the weather in Ecuador is similar most of the year, but in the South of Peru it is much colder in the winter. So depending on when you go, you may want to go to Peru in the period that is closer to summer (our winter). On the other hand, Machu Picchu is less busy in the low season and the Inca trail is closed in February.

Comment: When is the low season for Machu Picchu?

Comment: The high season is in between June and August because it is cooler and dryer in the Andes and North American and Europeans have their summer vacation. So the rest of the year should be low season. Places will be less crowded.

Answer (score 5):

I am a native from Ecuador. I have been in the Galapagos with my nieces and nephews and I think it will be a great experience for kids (6 and up) if they are young explorers that want to have fun while having activities with an educational approach.

Young kids could learn about endangered animals and habitats, and about Darwin and his theory of evolution.  The activities start really early in the morning so be sure the kids have had a good rest the night before.

For the route I would first visit the Islands and then Peru.

Comment: welcome to Travel.SE. Could you expand your answer to explain why you would visit the islands before Peru?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently visited the Galapagos with family having 3 kids, they enjoyed a lot there and Specially Galapagos is the best place to visit. There are no such problems we faced during our tour because of children, as we have already booked out the tour and they include all the important amenities required for small children. Our overall trip was awesome.

Comment: Could you expand on activities kids participated on